# problems with concurrency doctrine symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities `User` and `AbstractContent` with a ManyToMany relationship on each side and one attribute(e.g class below) for the association so I create one entity `UserAbstractContent` for the association.

The problem is when I try to insert a new row `AbstractContent` with one or more row in the table(entity) `UserAbstractContent` I have errors.

Class UserAbstractContent :

```
class UserAbstractContent
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="push\Bundle\PushBundle\Entity\AbstractContent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;
    //Reviser
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="push\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(name="accept", type="boolean",nullable=true)
     */
    private $accept;

}
```

The Controller :

```
// I save the AbstractContent
$em->persist($abstractContent);
$em->flush();
// getUsersByphones is a method to get the users with their phone numbers
$users = $em->getRepository("pushUserBundle:User")
            ->getUsersByphones($contactsConverted);
// a loop to link every user with the AbstractContent
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userAbstractContent = new UserAbstractContent();
    $userAbstractContent->setContent($abstractContent);
    $userAbstractContent->setUser($user);
    $em->persist($userAbstractContent);
}
$em->flush();
```

The AbstractContent is saved on the database, but the UserAbstractcontent is not saved here is the sql error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 
'INSERT INTO UserAbstractContent(read,accept,content_id,user_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)' 
with paramas[null,null,60,3] sql state 42000  syntax error or access violation.
```

Where

1. 60 : the AbstractContentent ID
2. 3 : The user ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is quite simple. You are probably using a reserved column name. By the looks of it, you are probably using MySQL. Here is the list of [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) there. You can see that the word `read` is a reserved word.

Try renaming the column by setting:

```
class UserAbstractContent {
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="some_other_name")
    */
   public $read;
}
```

It is not necessary to rename the entity property, but it's considered good practice to have the property and column name match. It makes life a lot easier. So if it's not a lot of work, rename `$read` to reflect the name of your table's column.

Comment: thx u so much u saved my day i renamed the column and the attribute like you suggested thx again

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!